# Christoffel symbols determined by Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, general-relativity

We can calculate the curvature tensor and sectional curvature using Christoffel symbols. However, can we express Christoffel symbols using curvature or sectional curvature? Is there a specific equation, such as $\Gamma_{ij}^k = f(Curvature)$?

There is no known explicit expression for the Christoffel symbol as a function of curvature or sectional curvature. Are there any special cases where the Christoffel symbol can be expressed in terms of curvature or sectional curvature?

Comment: As far as I remember, the book *Gravitation* by Misner, Thorne & Wheeler nicely develops a recipe how to find a metric from the Riemann tensor. Chrisoffel symbols follow from the metric.

Comment: Since the curvature depends on not only the pointwise values of Christoffel symbols but also their partial derivatives, could you say more about what kind of formula you’re looking for?

Comment: Connection determines curvature but not vice-versa. It is unclear to me what are you asking. Take a look [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100281/does-the-curvature-determine-the-metric), maybe this is what you'd like to know.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you, this link is very helpful. If I can calculate the metric through curvature, then it is obvious that I can also calculate the Christoffel symbols through curvature. My main goal is to solve a reverse problem because calculating the Christoffel symbols and curvature from the metric is straightforward. However, it's an interesting question how to calculate the metric and Christoffel symbols from higher-order expansions of curvature.

Comment: @Deane Please forgive me for not asking in a professional manner and not having a clear understanding of the concept. I just heard from others that Christoffel symbols can be expressed through the expansion term of curvature, so I am curious about how it is specifically represented because I think this is a reverse problem. Now, with these valuable comments, I plan to further study it.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you very much for your comment. I have only studied some basic concepts and calculations of Riemannian geometry. I will look into the topics related to the book you recommended. Indeed, if we can express metric through curvature, then Christoffel symbols become obvious.

Comment: @KurtG. any chance you could say more about the recipe?

Comment: @Deane. Took a brief look at MTW but I believe I remembered it the wrong way round. What they do in §14.6 is to start with a metric and calculate the curvature. Sorry for the confusion. The reverse is surely not unique but it is an interesting problem.

Comment: [This MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/100281/340165) is very related as pointed out by Moishe Kohan already.